# How do jet fighters get to war?

Tags: military, fighter, jet, range, ferry-flight

Currently Australia is [deploying F/A-18E/F Super Hornets to the UAE](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-09-18/prime-minister-to-farewell-troops-at-williamtown-raaf-base/5753396) to fight in Iraq. Obviously the UAE (and Iraq) is a very long way from Australia and well beyond the typical range of one of these aircraft.

On TV they literally showed the Australian Prime Minister waving goodbye while the jets took off and flew into the distance, which for some reason seemed odd and made me wonder about how fighter jets are typically ferried to a distant war.

I kind of assumed they were loaded onto an aircraft carrier and shipped there, but Australia doesn't have an aircraft carrier so obviously this isn't the case.

I assume they must therefore fly, but:

- Do they fly hop to hop within their usual range refuelling at each stop? Where would these stops be? I assume they can't just refuel at a civilian airport in an arbitrary country and would have to be an air force base belonging to a close ally.
- Do they fly continuously with aerial refuelling? Does the tanker need to make hops to refuel?
- Do they swap their weapons for extended fuel tanks which provide enough range to fly continuously to the UAE?
- Are they actually shipped via regular military cargo ship and the "departure" on TV just for show?
- If they do fly continuously, it seems like flying non-stop for ~13 hours in a cramped fighter pilot cockpit would be unreasonable (even commercial pilots take shifts), or would they fly supersonic and perhaps reduce this to 5 or 6 hours?

Answers don't necessarily have to be Australia -> UAE specific, I'd also be interested to know how the US deployed to Iraq and Afghanistan for example and if the process is consistent or depends on the aircraft and location.

Comment: To fly the planes across half the globe is easy. The hard part is to ferry all the rest there in time, so operations can start soon. You wouldn't believe how many tons of equipment and how many people are needed to keep one modern fighter aircraft flying.

Comment: Exactly, flying the fighters there is easy, the real question is how do you get the bombs, replacement parts, and service personnel there.

Comment: Another (much more expensive and only used as a last resort) option is to [put them in a C-5 Galaxy](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-UdLUW_S1MGw/URQDQkfE_CI/AAAAAAAAAeY/wA-xi3rEdPk/s1600/110818-F-XH170-156w.jpg). In a situation where an F-18 was damaged to the point of being unflyable on its own, the USAF took its wings and stabilizer fins off and [flew it back to the U.S. in a C-5](http://www.airforcetimes.com/article/20110827/NEWS/108270301/C-5-hauls-fighter-back-U-S-repairs).

Comment: Regarding the fourth hypothesis: Military equipment (not specifically fighter jets) is sometimes shiped through *commercial* cargo ships, even for the US.

Comment: @GdD this is very true. As a USAF veteran who had F-15 mechanic friends, each hour in the air requires two hours of maintenance on the ground. Plus, all those mechanics and pilots need tons of support: food, barracks, parts, etc. I tell people that out of over 300k Airmen, over 290k are _not_ pilots or aircrew. I can only answer "what kind of plane did you fly?" with "a desk" so many times.

Comment: All correct, but the support isn't needed immediately and it doesn't have to come from the same place. In this example, Australia is sending F-18s to the Middle East. The USAF is already there, is somewhat familiar with the F-18 and can handle whatever is needed until the AU support staff arrive by ship.

Comment: @paul, support staff are easy, a couple of C130 loads or a couple of chartered airliner or two. Although you can fly engines, spare parts, and even weapons, it's much more economical to put them on a ship.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that F-18E's have much larger fuel tanks than the C versions, and the E can carry 3 large external fuel tanks that more than double its fuel capacity iirc. Plus, it is capable of air refueling. And the hornet is far from slow.

Comment: Dear any fighter jet pilots looking for answers on this question: you looked in the wrong place.

Comment: Regarding your final bullet point, demanding people do unreasonable things is traditional for the military, and I have it on good authority that fighter pilots hate transporting planes.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To answer the list in order:

**Do they fly hop to hop?**

An F-18 can go 3,000km unloaded (ordnance adds a *lot* of drag) and that's plenty from Australia. You can get to the Middle East in 4 hops, no air-to-air refuelling required. Although if you do an in-flight top-up you can add more than the regular range because you don't need to burn any fuel getting back up to cruise altitude.

**Where would these stops be? Surely not at civilian airports?**

Military aircraft often use civilian airports - they run on Jet-A just like everything else. Fighters were not an uncommon sight at the general-aviation terminal where I'm from. Loaded warplanes are a political issue, unloaded ones are a good day's business for the airport's fuel merchants. (note that fighters are almost never completely unloaded - the ammunition for the gun has a significant effect on the airplane's trim. But you can't see it.)

An external fuel tank can be added in place of weapons.

**Are they actually shipped via regular military cargo ship?**

Fixed-wing aircraft are typically not boxed for surface shipping. Helicopters are - no wings to remove and rotors can be folded up very easily.
Carrier-based aircraft will depart from land - the only way you get a Hornet off of a docked carrier is with a crane, so they typically launch everything when still offshore, and load the aircraft the same way on departure.

The USA has enough carriers that they would not deploy a carrier-based fleet like this. If they are adding / replacing aircraft there are probably enough already in Europe - send those where needed and replace them in the normal course of events.

**Would they fly supersonic to reduce travel time?**

No, they won't go supersonic to reduce the flight time. > Mach 1 consumes so much fuel you'd never get there. Fighters have supersonic capability so they can get there or run away as needed, but it's never used for very long. The Concorde was designed from the beginning for Mach 2 cruise, so it didn't use afterburners once at Mach 2. Subsonic flight suffered as a result, fighters would not accept the subsonic flight handling issues as that's rather important to them :-)

Bombers are often deployed directly from home bases. All modern strategic bombers have global range with in-flight refuelling. You don't leave North Dakota, blow up something in Longwayfromherestan and get home for dinner, but you don't land anywhere else either. Yes, it's many hours in the same seat but the military crews are used to it.

Comment: Given all this info, my guess would be that OP's TV takeoffs were heading to meet up with their carrier offshore. Also, in terms of "butt in seat" time for a bomber on a long haul - those cockpits are probably much confier than tiny fighters would be.

Comment: @abbyhairboat except australia has no carriers for conventional fixed wing aircraft (harriers, yes).

Comment: "bomber...those cockpits are probably much confier than tiny fighters would be" - Bomber crews are strapped into ejection seats too. But they can get up.

Comment: @flyingfisch just a turn of phrase- I meant that the matter of what the fighters were doing taking off on TV is more complicated than I originally thought.

Comment: Some fighters (such as the F-22) have supercruise capability, so no afterburners required. No idea how it affects fuel consumption though.

Comment: Aren't the Aussie F/A-18s equipped for In-Flight Refueling? In which case they'd take off from a runway, stay at altitude for a LONG time, hit a tanker or two along the way and finally land at the destination.  When my (USAF) unit deployed F-16s to the Sandbox, that's what we did.  A bunch of Vipers and a KC-10 full of fuel, personnel and equipment.  The autopilot works well enough that the pilots don't get too fatigued (energy drinks help).  May have to use a "piddle pack," though.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Given all the info in the answer (in particular, the fact that a Hornet can fly for 3000km on one tank of fuel), *I* concluded that the televised take-off was the start of a four-hop flight to the Middle East. The answer almost says that in as many words!

Comment: Can a F-18 take off with ALL there tanks filled up?   If not mid-air refueling very close to take off location could make a big difference.

Comment: Military aircraft don't run on Jet A except in the United States; in most of the rest of the world, they run on Jet A-1 (like civilian jets and turboprops in said most of rest of world do too), while, in China and the former Soviet Union, they run on the Chinese and Soviet national jet fuels, respectively.

Answer (score 82):

I am former fighter pilot:

We often fly "hop to hop" but depending on the total distance, the need for urgency, and the distance over water we also fly with tankers and air refuel. Of course the tankers sometimes don't have the fuel for themselves and for us. In those cases, we'll just leave one tanker and rendezvous with another tanker enroute. Everything is very carefully planned. The longest I spent in an F-16 seat was 14 hours. It wasn't too bad.

Comment: It's funny. Flying an F-16 has a glamorous and dangerous image. 14 hours alone with nothing to look at but a clear sky sounds... kind of boring.

Comment: @Chris, what altitude and airspeed do you maintain during long flights? Is it in the order of FL500+?

Comment: @Chris Do you guys have to plan alternate airports too for these logistic placement flights? It'd be mighty uncomfy to ditch a multimillion jet because your target hop airport shut down.

Comment: @curious_cat I think pretty much all pilots try to make sure they have alternate landing possibilities within their fuel range, especially for long distance flights.

Comment: @steveverrill except you have what, better than 180º of view around you. That's a heck of a lot cooler than the teeny windows you get on your run of the mill airliner...

Comment: @steveverrill - as they say, "War is weeks of interminable boredom punctuated by moments of sheer terror". Peace is the same, but more... :-)

Comment: How did you stave off boredom in an F-15 for *14 hours?*

Comment: @LevelRiverSt spoke to an RCAF Hornet pilot a few months ago. Many of them carry an iPod with some audiobooks and music during long patrols or ferry flights.

Comment: @jwenting Does the Hornet really have an iPod jack?

Comment: @DJClayworth I guess they plug in the 3.5mm audio plug into their headset somehow, or wear earbuds under the headset. They didn't tell me how they did it, just that they did it.

Answer (score 32):

Ferry range of an FA18-E/F (with ferry tanks attached) is ~ 1800nm.

There are any number of possible routes from YAMB to DHF. The choice of route will be influenced by weather, speed, and  politics (third country over flight and landing rights).  It is also possible to mix ferry and refueling.

One could, for example, do [YAMB-DCN-CCK-NKW-DHF](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=drw,lea,kul,NKW,xch,DPS,VTZ,bom,cmb,yamb-drw-dps-kul-vtz-dhf,dps,yamb-dcn-cck-trv-dhf,yamb-dcn-cck-nkw-dhf&DU=nm) (see image below) with a mid-air refueling between NKW & DHF if one wanted, for whatever reason, to avoid landing in India or Sri Lanka.

[image: Map of various routes from YAMB to DHF]

Answer (score 29):

Good Question! They are typically flown in legs from Australia, or if long distance over water, conduct air - air refuelling.

The Super Hornets you are talking about will most likely stop at somewhere like Butterworth in Malaysia, then fly onto Dubai, possibly meeting with the MRTT sent the day before to refuel enroute.

Australia does not have any Aircraft Carriers so sadly, we have to ferry flight them everywhere.

Answer (score 14):

They may do hop to hop or they may use inflight refueling.

Of course that opens up the problem of the tankers having enough fuel. Not all tankers can re-fuel in the air, but some can.

When the RAF did the Black Buck raids in the Falklands war (~12000km), they were offered the use of US Stratotankers. They decided it would not work because the Stratotankers cold not refuel in the air (perhaps they can now, I do not know).

They used their own Victors, which [refueled each other](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Refuelling.plan.black.buck.svg#mediaviewer/File:Refuelling.plan.black.buck.svg), ultimately leaving the Vulcan to carry on on its own.

Alternatively, you could use tankers that are already positioned on route, which was the USAF does when it B-52 strike the middle east from their bases in continental US

Comment: Whats the point of having a tanker that cannot refuel midair. It is the fact that they use different refueling system and that makes one useless tanker.

Comment: The really interesting story was the initial Vulcan raid on the Port Stanley airfield. One Vulcan, twelve Victors to refuel the Vulcan and each other, and they had only a couple of weeks to practice Vulcan aerial refueling, which they hadn't done in ages. They pulled it off. Good doc on this on youtube.

Comment: @tj1000 they also had to re-add the capability to the Vulcans too. Part of the re-fueling probe was being used as an ash tray in the mess at a nearby airfield apparently

Answer (score 10):

You can't land just any plane on an aircraft carrier, it has to have tail hooks and the pilot needs special training. The Aussie F/A-18s are not equipped to land on aircraft carriers. So they have to do short 'hops' or in flight re-fuel.

Comment: The bigger issue here is that Australia doesn't *have* any aircraft carriers to land on.

Comment: @raptortech97 I am surprised that Australia does not have aircraft carriers, any reason

Comment: @Firee http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAS_Melbourne_(R21)#HMS_Invincible ... Canada doesn't either, nor Japan, nor any country in the Middle East nor Africa ... only about [15 countries do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_carriers_by_country).

Comment: Actually, Japan sort of has carriers, they just don't call them that. They're called the Hyuga class 'helicopter destroyers', although an F35B could also operate from them. I'm sure that never occurred to the IJN when they built those 'helicopter destroyers'...

Comment: @ChrisW you'd think that a big island nation would want to have a navy to defend it's SLOCs.

Comment: @RonJohn The USA's military expenditure is nearly 30 times the size of Australia's. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_military_expenditures

Comment: @ChrisW so... like Europe, Australia is riding free (not totally, but close enough) off the USA?

Comment: @RonJohn The States used to spend as much as the rest of the world put together! Now it's only 40% of world spending but no other single country is in the same league. Many countries spend 2% of their GDP -- that's the NATO target and Australia does that too -- America spends 4% of its GDP, but its GDP is so much higher too. Europe doesn't exactly ride free, its military spending is 50% of the States' (i.e. for the whole of Europe aggregated) but no other country has a navy to touch America's. FWIW America like other countries benefits economically from international trade (i.e. your "SLOCs").

Comment: @ChrisW Europe rides free, because much of what they call "defense" spending is really on internal security.

Answer (score 9):

These articles [[1](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/06/05/f35_delivery_flight_raf_marham_delayed/), [2]](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/06/07/f_35s_arrive_raf_marham_us_gao_reliability_report/) from The Register describe the procedure followed, when a couple of F-35 jet were delivered from the US to the UK. Crossing the Atlantic in a peace-time delivery could well be compared with moving fighters from their home base towards a base nearer to the theather of conflict.

In one of the articles several means of delivery are discussed: direct crossing, fly a more overland route (as in pre ETOPS times), or delivery by ship.

**Direct flight**
With a direct long-haul flight, you need to take air refueling into account and take precautions for the case when something goes wrong. Especially, with single-engine planes. Thus, the F-35s were accompanied by tankers and a A-400 M to provide sea rescue capabilities.

**Overland route**
An overland route is the safe option for non-ETOPS planes. However, this involves a lot of diplomatic activity. In contrast to civil aviation, armed forces are supposed to ask prior to entering other countries' air space.

**Delivery by ship**
This is by far the safest option. However, this involves some logistics. First, (partial) disassembly, shipping and re-assembly at their destination. While being very safe, this is the least glamorous way to Air Force business.

Comment: Even being carried by ship carries _some_ risks. This brand-new [railway locomotive](https://www.flickr.com/photos/dbdi/5536939531) was damaged beyond economic repair when it was dropped while being unloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Generally fighters will fly long ferry routes together as a squadron with multiple tanker rendezvous enroute for fuel.  Most of the squadron personnel and equipment will be airlifted in cargo aircraft to the base of operations but the fighters will be flown there by the pilots.  Flight planning generally dictates alternate land bases must be within flying range as well in the event an aircraft in the flight cannot successfully tank.  Cruise speeds for ferry flights are not supersonic but in the Mach 0.8-0.9 range.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, ferry flights are done with aux tanks when possible, and no ordnance on the aircraft.  The logistics are influenced by the urgency, the geo political situation, the location of friendly countries, their assets, and airports to land at, and staffing.

Ferry flights are preferred over boats for many aircraft, as once an aircraft is on a boat is is typically not available for a period of time, and needs special equipment to load and off load.

Logistics has to handle overflight permits, etc. and rapidly deployed aircraft will often have over water routing to reduce permit requirements.  Additionally there may be some interest in reduced media coverage. Landing 16 fighters in Dubai to top the tanks is not done except where the visibility is desired, and most stops are done at bases or bases of allied forces.

It is noteworthy that certain flights, for example, B-2 runs, are originated out of mid-continent US, and return to that base afterwards. They are supported by tankers, and in the case of the B-2 it avoids the risk of landing a plane at a remote location.

For the US and allied forces, there is coordination by logistics, so that Navy assets are tasked with providing support in the unlikely event of off shore crew recovery, support, etc.  For example, I know that US Navy has been advised of AUS deployments, and provides offshore services for asset movements.

Such movements are routine.  For example, a NY Guard unit has supported South Pole NSF operations, and the C-130 used is ferried from New York to the South Pole and back after the missions are complete.