# Do carrier-less militaries retain the equipment for carrier operations?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, aircraft-carrier

"[How do jet fighters get to war?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/how-do-jet-fighters-get-to-war)" made me wonder if aircraft used by the U.S. Navy and U.S. Marine Corps for carrier operations retain their carrier equipment when sold to foreign powers who do not operate carriers?

**Pros** would be the reduction in weight, repair/maintenance complexity, and cost (why bother paying for equipment you don't use?).

**Cons** would be engineering complexity (if they're not designed as optional components) or airworthiness (if the components have secondary functions beyond carrier operations).

The initial thought was prompted by a [CATOBAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CATOBAR) aircraft, but if something like the [Harrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet) has different equipment, that would be relevant, too. What's the reality?

Comment: Another pro to removing the equipment would be be stocked up oin spare parts

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taking the [RAAF F/A-18's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet_in_Australian_service) for example:

> The Australian Hornets were very similar to the standard US Navy variants, but incorporated a number of minor modifications [including] the deletion of all equipment used to launch the aircraft using catapults.

Even though they retain the [tailhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailhook), if they landed on a carrier, they won't be able to takeoff.

The tailhook serves the same function as on the land-based F-15 and F-16, provide arrested landing capability for emergency situations.

[image]
([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USAF_F-16_hooks_an_arresting_cable.jpg)) F-16 arrested landing.

As for the Harrier, all the [foreign operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet#Operators) were navies. So, export Harriers were used on carriers. (Rhyming unintentional.)

The carrier-borne [Rafale fighter jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Rafale#India) will retain its carrier capability when sold to the Indian Navy.

Comment: I was unaware the F-15 and F-16 even *had* arrestor hooks!

Comment: @T.J.L. - Liar!! :P

Comment: Hey! I'm just recreating the thought over here. I'm not the liar, the timestamp is the liar. I *was* unaware of it at *one point*. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. - I know :D I actually smiled at the comment :)

Comment: Thanks for moving the answer over, though. That's a great picture you found.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast having different configurations for different customers is pretty much the standard for aircraft. Usually it's minor (like a different nosegear strut for carrier operations or a few different avionics boxes), sometimes it may be larger (like the conformal fuel tanks on Israeli F-16s, which were developed for them and never ordered by any other customer).

Comment: @jwenting - I think UAE bought those tanks as well.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - agreed and I revised the answer, you sent me mixed signals in the first comment though :D

Comment: Ooops, forgot the up vote yesterday.  Like this answer. Thanks for the comment that ended up as a reminder.

Comment: @ymb1 maybe they did, but not at the time Israel ordered them. They were the first, the tanks were created specifically for them and later offered to other customers as well.

Comment: U Marine Corps flies the Harrier, but not the Navy. Still use them on carriers thought. The F35 actually has 3 different versions, with only the_C_ variant being hardened for carrier use.

Comment: Technically, the USMC uses Harriers on *amphibs* (aka straight-decks), not on *carriers*. I'm guessing it's possible (even likely) that one has landed on a carrier for some reason, but I cannot recall ever hearing of any Harrier squadrons deploying on a carrier (for many reasons).

Comment: @ymb1 Sorry for the super-delayed-reaction on the acceptance. I meant to do it many, many months ago. :)

Answer (score 10):

#### The most common case is that the aircraft sold to non CATOBAR navies/air forces is built to a different configuration.

For example, the [Canadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_CF-18_Hornet), Spanish, and Swiss F-18's were each sold under a different configuration.  Some of the weight penalties, maintenance and upkeep costs, and the substantial training costs to maintain CATOBAR currency and proficiency were not a concern and not needed.  This makes sense: since those flying services didn't have a carrier operations requirement, but they liked a variety of features that the Hornet provided (such as two engines).

> Reasons for the selection listed by the Canadian Forces were many of
>   its requested features were included for the U.S. Navy; two engines
>   for reliability (considered essential for conducting Arctic
>   sovereignty and over-the-water patrols), an excellent radar set, while
>   being considerably more affordable than the F-14 and the F-15. The
>   CF-18 was procured from 1982 to 1988, at a total capital cost of $4
>   billion in 1982 dollars.

Interestingly, that early Canadian buy retained most of the CV features, and IIRC they were the first non US buyer of the aircraft. (Memory foggy on that one).

> Export Hornets are typically similar to U.S. models of a similar
>   manufacture date. Since none of the customers operate aircraft
>   carriers, [all export models have been sold without the automatic
>   carrier landing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet#cite_note-Jenkins-24), and Royal Australian Air Force further removed
>   the catapult attachment on the nose gear.[24]

For the non CATOBAR case, [the current plan to deploy Marine F-35B's on Royal Navy carriers answers the rest of your question](https://news.usni.org/2015/09/17/dsei-u-s-marine-f-35bs-will-operate-from-british-queen-elizabeth-carriers).

> LONDON — The U.S. Marine Corps will deploy its Lockheed Martin F-35B
>   Lightning II strike fighters on combat sorties from Britain’s new
>   Queen Elizabeth-class aircraft carriers, a senior U.K. Royal Navy
>   officer has confirmed.

Comment: @T.J.L.  Oops, thanks, got it.

Comment: Tthe QEs are STOVL carriers, and the F-35B is a STOVL fighter. So this is actually its intended use case. A dozen or two will also be sold to the Italian air force to operate from short runways, rather than STOVL carriers. I don't think they're changing any equipment though.

Comment: @HephaestusAetnaean What I have found in FMS is a variety of configuration differences that are subtle (Perhaps certain mission systems) and not a carbon copy.  As I don't have detailed info on the differences in F-35B (USMC) and F-35B (UK) I can't go any further. (I first encountered this with the USN Seahawk vs Australian Seahawk/S-70) and later in F-18 and F-16 configuration differences.